# Group By clause causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So here is the context : Developping an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app, I have in my database a table **ProductAllocations** which is composed of 2 foreign keys : one from my table **Products** and the other from the table **Persons**. I have another table, **Vehicles** which contains a foreign key of the table **Products**

I want to select the allocations and their information grouped by a product (a product can be allocated several time). Here is my stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetAllVehicles

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    SELECT 

    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName,
    pa.EndDate,
    pr.PurchaseDate,
    pr.SerialNumber,
    pr.CatalogPrice,
    v.PlateNumber,
    v.FirstCirculationDate,
    V.FirstDrivingTax,
    v.UsualDrivingTax

    FROM bm_ProductAllocations AS pa

    INNER JOIN bm_Persons AS p ON pa.Id_Person = p.Id_Person
    INNER JOIN bm_Products AS pr ON pa.Id_Product = pr.Id_Product
    INNER JOIN bm_Vehicles AS v ON pr.Id_Product = v.Id_Product

    GROUP BY pa.Id_Product

END
```

However, the Group By clause is generating an error : `Column 'bm_Persons.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` I'm working with Visual Studio 2010.

I'm new to SQL so I have no idea about what's going on.

Comment: I removed the MVC and Visual Studio 2010 tags, since this issue isn't relevant to either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *fields* you *group by*, you need to either use an aggregation `sum`, `max` etc or you need to include the columns in the clause, see the following links: [SQL Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) &  [summarizing values](http://www.thunderstone.com/site/texisman/summarizing_values.html)

```
SELECT   p.FirstName
        ,p.LastName
        ,pa.EndDate
        ,pr.PurchaseDate
        ,pr.SerialNumber
        ,pr.CatalogPrice
        ,v.PlateNumber
        ,v.FirstCirculationDate
        ,v.FirstDrivingTax
        ,v.UsualDrivingTax
FROM     bm_ProductAllocations AS pa
INNER JOIN bm_Persons AS p ON pa.Id_Person = p.Id_Person
INNER JOIN bm_Products AS pr ON pa.Id_Product = pr.Id_Product
INNER JOIN bm_Vehicles AS v ON pr.Id_Product = v.Id_Product
GROUP BY pa.Id_Product
        ,p.FirstName
        ,p.LastName
        ,pa.EndDate
        ,pr.PurchaseDate
        ,pr.SerialNumber
        ,pr.CatalogPrice
        ,v.PlateNumber
        ,v.FirstCirculationDate
        ,v.FirstDrivingTax
        ,v.UsualDrivingTax;
```

Answer (score 7):

To use a GROUP BY function you need to make sure all of the fields in your SELECT statement are in aggregate functions (e.g. SUM() or COUNT()), or they need to be in the GROUP BY function.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Group BY` you should whether put your fields you want to select in `Group By` clause or you should use aggregate functions on them , For example

```
SELECT 

    pa.Id_Product,Min(p.FirstName) as Firstname,Min(p.LastName) as LastName

    FROM bm_ProductAllocations AS pa

    INNER JOIN bm_Persons AS p ON pa.Id_Person = p.Id_Person
    INNER JOIN bm_Products AS pr ON pa.Id_Product = pr.Id_Product
    INNER JOIN bm_Vehicles AS v ON pr.Id_Product = v.Id_Product

    GROUP BY pa.Id_Product
```

you should know what aggregate function you want to use , there are many Min,max,Sum...

For more information read this [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use aggregate functions with Group By, however any column not being subjected to an aggregate function, but still selected, will need to be contained in the Group By

What exactly are you trying to do with this query?