# Join of two tables where result displays on min() field of table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, plsql

Working with sql procedure and encountering a problem to which not finding solution.

There is table A with fields a,b,c.
And a table B with fields a, w, x, y, z.

Here, I want the result of join of both tables where A.a = B.a and select fields like c, x, y, z in output where w is minimum. w is an integer.
Following code is helping but when i want to display more fields from table 2, getting an error saying Group by clause not included.

```
SELECT OutO.routingSequence, 
       tbl2.a AS parentOrderNumber, 
       tbl2.c AS operationNumber,
       tbl2.d as headerStatus,
       tbl2.e as orderNumber
FROM Operation OutO
JOIN (
    SELECT a, MIN(c) c 
    FROM (
        SELECT h.parentordernumber a, o.operationNumber c 
        FROM header h , operation o 
        WHERE o.ordernumber=h.Parentordernumber
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) < 3
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) > -5
    ) tbl 
    GROUP BY a
) tbl2 
ON OutO.ordernumber = tbl2.a
WHERE OutO.operationnumber = tbl2.c
```

Please help on this!!!

Comment: I've tried to reformat your SQL to make it more readable but it still doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  It doesn't look like valid SQL

Comment: new to stackoverflow and can't really format code. I hope following one works for you, this code is working and I am able to see desired result. However, if I want to add more fields for selection from table 2 I get an error. How to avoid this? and could there be any better logic?

Comment: @shalinimathur can update your question with error details and its better if you can add that query

Comment: code updated. Getting error in this code. Please help.

Comment: @shalinimathur I coudnt find column d and e in your inner query can i know  in which table its available

Comment: is it available on header or operation ?

Comment: Is the above code throws error? or not?

Comment: it is available in header.

Comment: @shalinimathur the issue is you haven't select them in inner select

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? DATEDIFF and GETDATE are both product specific functions...

Comment: I'm using sql server and these both functions are working with it

Answer (score 0):

Try it with distinct instead of group by

```
  Select DISTINCT OutO.routingSequence, tbl2.a as parentOrderNumber, tbl2.c as operationNumber from Operation OutO
```

Comment: okay, and what if i want to select more fields along with routing sequence? will it work?

Comment: GROUP BY table2.a                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314836/group-by-clause-causing-error i  think this will help you out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Updated SQL you have to select fields from inner select if you want to get it as output

```
SELECT OutO.routingSequence, 
       tbl2.a AS parentOrderNumber, 
       tbl2.c AS operationNumber,
       tbl2.d as headerStatus,
       tbl2.e as orderNumber
FROM Operation OutO
JOIN (
    SELECT a, MIN(c) c,MIN(d) AS d,MIN(e) as e
    FROM (
        SELECT h.parentordernumber as a, o.operationNumber as c ,h.headerStatus as d, h.orderNumber as e
        FROM header h inner join  operation o 
        on o.ordernumber=h.Parentordernumber
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) < 3
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) > -5
    ) tbl 
    GROUP BY a
) tbl2 
ON OutO.ordernumber = tbl2.a
WHERE OutO.operationnumber = tbl2.c
```

Comment: Try this and let me know

Comment: I'm getting following error:
Column 'tbl.d' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

if I add Group by clause for field d, then I will get replicated data which I don't want.
So here, what should be the logic to select multiple fields from table 2 where field 1 is minimum, Provided join with table 1 for some field 2.

Comment: can i know the data type of column d

Comment: what is the value your trying to get from that column max ,min or some thing like taht

Comment: min column type is integer, c and d are also integer

Comment: then get min from those two columns ill update the query

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, I don't want to select min of other fields, as these fields are numeric and should display corresponding to min(operationNumber), selecting min of other fields will change the output.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i don't understand where is d and e and w columns is your sql
you can use row_number and partition by, to get ordered by min value first row like this

```
SELECT OutO.routingSequence, 
       tbl2.a AS parentOrderNumber, 
       tbl2.c AS operationNumber,
       tbl2.d as headerStatus,
       tbl2.e as orderNumber
FROM Operation OutO
JOIN (
       select a,c,e,d from (
        SELECT h.parentordernumber a, o.operationNumber c,
               something1 as d,
               something2 as e,
               -- where this = 1 there is your minimum row
               row_number() over (partition by h.parentordernumber
                                      order by w ) Rn
        FROM header h , operation o 
        WHERE o.ordernumber=h.Parentordernumber
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) < 3
        AND (
            SELECT DATEDIFF(day,o.scheduledStartDate, GETDATE()) AS DiffDate
        ) > -5
   ) where Rn = 1 -- here we need only first row in every windows
) tbl2 
ON OutO.ordernumber = tbl2.a
WHERE OutO.operationnumber = tbl2.c
```

Comment: Hi, getting error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'", indicating towards "where Rn = 1"

Comment: u can read the manual about row_number over partition by here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms186734.aspx. My example just example and i'm not compile this sql. is you use mssql or there https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm if you use Oracle plsql