# How to select best customers and group them by how much they paid

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I am using SQL server to select this table and group the customer id and first name according to their total payments made to the store. I tried using

```
select custid, name, sum(payment)
from transactions
group by custid
order by payment desc
```

but it returns the following error:

> not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Could you please clarify what I did wrong?

this is my customer table

| cust id | payment | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 60 | katy |
| T002 | 12 | amy |
| T003 | 40 | leon |
| T001 | 20 | katy |

this is the result table I want to get

| cust id | payment | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | 80 | katy |
| T003 | 12 | amy |
| T002 | 40 | leon |

Comment: If you're SELECTing both Custid and Name, then you need to GROUP BY both Custid and Name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group By clause causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314836/group-by-clause-causing-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the *name* or *payment* columns, both of which you refer to without aggregating.

You need to *order by* the same expression or provide the column an alias; column name inconsistencies aside, try:

```
select Cust_Id, sum(Payment) as TotalPayment, Name
from transactions
group by Cust_Id, Name
order by TotalPayment desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a space in your cust id column. Your code does not contain the space. Try it with a space between cust and id.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).